# Java style: Multiple variable assignment

Tags: java, variables, syntax, coding-style, variable-assignment

Take the following:

```
if (filter instanceof FileNameExtensionFilter) {
    fnef = (FileNameExtensionFilter) filter;
    String[] extensions = fnef.getExtensions();
    if (extensions.length > 1) {
        fnef = filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(fnef.getDescription(), extensions[0]);
    }
}
```

where `filter` is a `FileFilter` object and `fnef` an instance variable of the type `FileNameExtensionFilter`.

Would you consider it good coding practice to assign a value to multiple variables on the same line? Or would it be better to write line 6 from the example as follows:

```
fnef = new FileNameExtensionFilter(fnef.getDescription(), extensions[0]);
filter = fnef;
```

I personally prefer the latter, though I'd like to hear what you think.

Comment: Why do you even need two variables referring to the same object?

Comment: @Don `fnef` is a field which stores the reference to the object for the whole class to use, given that the object is a `FileNameExtensionFilter`; on the other hand, `filter` is a local variable in the method where the code snipped I posted is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty subjective question.

I think this is more clear:

```
fnef = new FileNameExtensionFilter(fnef.getDescription(), extensions[0]);
filter = fnef;
```

But any experienced developer will understand this:

```
fnef = filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(fnef.getDescription(), extensions[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use separate lines to avoid confusions when using non-immutable objects like FileNameExtensionFilter. For example it's not the same to say:

```
MyObject var1 = new MyObject();
MyObject var2 = new MyObject();
```

Than

```
MyObject var1, var2;
var1 = var2 = new MyObject();
```

In the first case the variables are different objects with the same values but in the second case they are the same variable. Multiple variable assignment is risky so I do consider it bad practice. It's still a matter of taste.